# How does the Innistrad "no spells / two or more spells cast last turn" transform trigger work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

On some of the two sided cards the cards ability says "At the beginning of each upkeep, if no spells were cast last **turn** transform (card name)".  [Mayor of Avabruck](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMayor%20of%20Avabruck%5d)

Does "**turn**" refers to the opponents last turn, or the opponents turn before the other player?

I have a entire deck that has these cards but it don't understand it.

Comment: i mean the way i use it is, I just transform them if no spells were cast by the last opponent, but i do not feel that is right.  That makes it to easy for it to transform but that how i been using them.  If that is not how there used then I been using them all wrong.  So if anyone knows please help clear things up.

Comment: okay now i am ticked off you completely just changed everything this is almost not even my question anymore it been edited by you devs. which has just ticked me off what happen to the freedom of text.  You have one completely change the structure and then you had another that has completely change the dang title.  Is this a question website for people to get answer or is this a site for the devs. or the higher players to get attention and not allow anyone to express there question in their own way.

Comment: The people who made the edits to your question are users just like you or me not Stack exchange developers. They are just trying to help make the question a bit better formatted or easier to read, if you feel like the edits change the meaning of your question you are welcome to go and modify them to something that matches your original intentions. The idea is to make the questions clear and easily searchable, but not to insult you or say that your questions are unreadable.

Comment: Bull I got banned because it was revised now I cannot even ask questions I mean no my question isn't what originally posted anymore I think the players need to work on suggesting first i learn by experience not by other people doing things for me.  So i do not like my original items being touched unless I was asked and agreed to it.  im sure every one knows what it was about.

Comment: Did you recently ask a question/write an answer that was downvoted and then deleted? If so your account/IP might have been automatically limited. Generally you can come back from this by writing a [well written, and upvoted answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Don't worry no one is out to get you, just looks like you got a bit caught in the automatic processes. Additionally this question seems to be doing well now, so you may find the blocks just go away on their own.

Comment: @LoneWolf That's how stackexchange sites work, they're not just about you asking a question and getting it answered, they are about making sure your question is asked in such a way that other people who have the same question will be easily able to find it, as well as making sure that people are easily able to understand and answer it. This is not a discussion board where your posts are your own.

Comment: @LoneWolf if you want your content to stay your own and only modifiable if YOU agree to it..... Stack may not be the proper network for you :/. It's just how we do here.  You of course can always rollback edits on your own posts, or edit it again yourself, but the occasional edit from another user is to be expected here, and you really shouldn't get ticked off about this.

Comment: @LoneWolf I just read through the first (original) question and the edit, and I can't see any change that altered the meaning of the question; only changes to make it more readable. If there's a specific thing that you wanted to ask that is no longer being asked in the edit, please explain what it is.

Comment: I would like to clarify that question bans are not impacted by others editing your question. If new users ask questions that get downvoted and/or deleted, they get limited in the rate at which they can ask questions. The best way to avoid hitting that rate limit is to ask questions that get upvoted, like this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "turn" is one player's go.

i.e. from the start of one player's upkeep step until just before the start of the next player's upkeep step.

Note that this triggers during *EACH* upkeep, so in *your* upkeep it will trigger if there were no spells during your opponent's turn and during your *opponent's* upkeep it will trigger if there were no spells during *your* turn.

Comment: that clears up so much.  i would never get anything transformed because i went a whole round around.  Well that was more simple than i made it out to be.  I am self taught so i didn't get no luxury a good trainer.  Thank you for helping me out on that

Comment: A side discussion about the meaning of "turn" in other games has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75115/discussion-on-answer-by-brondahl-how-does-the-innistrad-no-spells-two-or-more).

Answer (score 9):

**If it's your upkeep, the last turn is the turn that has most recently concluded (usually your opponents). If it's your opponent upkeep, the last turn is usually yours.**

What is a turn?

> 500.1. A turn consists of five phases, in this order: beginning, precombat main, combat, postcombat main, and ending. Each of these
>   phases takes place every turn, even if nothing happens during the
>   phase. The beginning, combat, and ending phases are further broken
>   down into steps, which proceed in order.

So a turn contains **all** the phases. But when is the upkeep?

> 501.1. The beginning phase consists of three steps, in this order: untap, upkeep, and draw.

It is in the beginning phase. **The whole turn before this point is the turn of the previous player.**

> 603.2e If a triggered ability’s trigger condition is met, but the object with that triggered ability is at no time visible to all
>   players, the ability does not trigger.

That whole turn will be checked to see if the condition has been met to so it can trigger.

Comment: This definition seems dangerous in a game where one player can take multiple turns in a row. It's entirely possible for it to be my turn, but the turn before this was mine, too.

Answer (score 2):

Since this triggers at **each** upkeep and doesn't specify what player has to cast the spells, it not only looks if your opponent cast a spell before your turn but generally if **any** player cast a spell during the turn before that upkeep. Doesn't have to be an opponent (e.g. multiplayer).

Take [Huntmaster of the Fells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2B%5BHuntmaster%20of%20the%20Fells%5D), who has a nice effect on both sides.

You are in full control over when he transforms and when not.

Want him to transform on your opponents upkeep? Simply cast nothing on your turn.

Want him to transform back on your turn? Make sure at least two spells are cast by any one player on your opponent's turn. <strike>These can even be your own spells or a mix of yours and your opponent's. A creature spell and a counterspell against that creature already count as two spells and will transform the Huntmaster back.</strike> After some testing in Magic Online it seems this is not correct and the card text does indeed say **a** player, so one player has to cast at least two spells.

Of course a clever opponent can just cast an instant during your turn to prevent him transforming the first time. It is best to not cast anything yourself when your opponent is tapped out to make sure the transform will happen.

Comment: You aren't in full control over when it transforms. your opponent can cast something simple on your turn, say shock or opt, and keep it human side up.

Answer (score 1):

It means the last actual turn, no matter who's turn it was then or is now, the transform ability checks on every player's upkeep, werewolves can actually transform back and forth every single turn.

It's more clear how it works in multiplayer games, when it's not just your turn then your opponent's turn. Lets look at an example:

It's your turn and you are playing one werewolf threat, since you don't want the rest to transform, say [Huntmaster of the Fells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHuntmaster%20of%20the%20Fells%5d), the blue player doesn't want you to do that, so they counter your spell. So far no single player has played two spells so your werewolves won't go back to human yet, but the blue player who's turn is next wants them to be human again and weaker, so he casts [Brainstorm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrainstorm%5d) before your turn ends. At the start of the blue player's turn your werewolves all transform since a player cast two spells, but this is a blue player, and he has nothing but counters and land from the cards left in his hand, so he casts nothing, and no one else casts anything, he ends his turn and the next player's turn begins. Because no one cast anything, all your werewolves transform again back to wolf side, this player plays a spell and the blue player counters it. Next it's your turn again, two spells were cast but since each player only cast one, your werewolves stay wolves and you get to bring their wolf side strength into combat on this turn.

Comment: Thanks for adding the important part that if you had the turn before that and had a second turn in a row, it would trigger again and "query" spells cast on the turn before.